# Какую важную информацию можно получить посредством команды strace?

Tags: linux, консоль

Например команда

```
strace ls
```

Выводит слишком много информации, и не ясно, какая информация более ценная.

Comment: Спасибо Вам за то, что Вы правильно написали слово "посредством".

Comment: Не понял, в чем прикол?

Comment: Теперь Вы все испортили словом "прикол".

Comment: @Igor, я не понимаю, извините...

Comment: Пожалуйста, не беспокойтесь. Это мои собственные проблемы. Я здесь регулярно натыкаюсь на это слово в виде "по средствам". Так что, когда вижу элементарную грамотность, сильно радуюсь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сам по себе вывод strace большой и сложный. Но если знать, что искать, то можно легко все найти. К примеру, запускаете программу, которая подключается к серверу, но не понимаете, куда именно она подключается. В любом случае, подключение должно пройти через connnect. Делаем так

```
strace -e connect curl google.com
```

и видим, что курл слишком много бегает:) ( у меня он сделал 8 connect вызовов).

Второй пример, хочется узнать, какие функции часто вызываются (такой себе профайлинг для бедных). Запускаем с параметром с

```
strace -c curl google.com
```

и получаем красивую таблицу. И теперь уже знаем, какой запрос фильтровать.

Третий, очень хороший пример. Постоянно пользуюсь. Работает демон, и что то приуныл. Девопсы бегают и не знают, что происходит. И я не php программист. Что делать?

- берем pgrep, top, htop или даже по старинке `ps aux | grep <процесс>` и смотрим pid зависшего процесса.
- подключаемся к нему `strace -p <pid>`.

Даже на этом этапе уже стает много понятно. Часто можно сразу диагностировать причину. Естественно, потом применяем -e и фильтруем запросы.

А теперь самый интересный.

```
timeout 10 strace -c -p <pid>
```

timeout запускает процесс на 10 секунд и остановит его. strace соберет статистику по процессу и покажет ее. В результате знаем, какие системные вызовы и в каком кол-ве процесс вызывал. Иногда результат очень просветляет.

Также не стоит забывать дружественную команду ltrace - которая делает все то же, но только с библиотечными функциями (даже много параметров командной строки совпадают).

Comment: А вообще пора на perf переходить, да...

Comment: То, что strace умеет делать немного бенчмарка, ещё не значит, что perf может его полностью заменить

Comment: А кто сказал, что perf только про бенчмарки?

Comment: а кто сказал, что strace только о бенчмарках. Линукс тем и хорош, что есть много инструментов, которыми можно решить свои проблемы. Если Вы умете им пользоваться - очень хорошо, напишите ответ, как он позволяет делать то, что и умеет делать strace. Будет очень полезно

Answer (score 0):

Команда strace в Linux позволяет отслеживать системные вызовы и сигналы. Вот синтаксис:

```
strace [OPTIONS] command
```

Предположим программа находиться по этому адресу `/usr/local/bin/cough`. Тогда просто используется следующая команда:

```
strace /usr/local/bin/cough  <далее любой требуемый аргумент>
```

или же

```
strace -o <out_file> /usr/local/bin/cough <далее любой требуемый аргумент>
```

для записи в `out_file`.

Весь вывод strace будет идти в `stderr` (будьте внимательны, его объем часто запрашивает перенаправление файла). В простейших случаях программа будет прервана с ошибкой, можно увидеть где ее последние взаимодействия с ОС в выводе `strace`.

**Как использовать команду strace?**

Основное использование простое, просто выполните 'strace' с командой в качестве входных данных.

Например, можно использовать его с командой `ls`:

```
strace ls
```

Вот результат в качестве примера:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выдержки из справочной предоставляют следующее описание:

> Каждая строка в трассировке содержит имя системного вызова, а затем ее аргументы в круглых скобках и его возвращаемое значение. Пример Strac команды "cat /dev/null":
>
> open("/dev/null", O_RDONLY) = 3
>
> Ошибки (обычно возвращаемое значение -1) имеют символ error и ошибку добавленной строки.
>
> open("/foo/bar", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (Нет такого файла или каталога)
>
> Сигналы печатаются как символы сигнала и декодированная структура `siginfo`. Выдержка из страйка и прерывание команды «sleep 666»:
>
> sigsuspend([] 
>   --- SIGINT {si_signo=SIGINT, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=...} ---
>              +++ killed by SIGINT +++